# Find word before specific phrase in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, linq

I'm trying to find left word located before specific phrase `"is better"` in all this cases, except **input 3**:

```
    string input = "I think that green bike is better than the red bike"; // input 1
    string input = "I think that green bike is better";                   // input 2
    string input = "is better than the red one";                          // input 3
    string input = "bike is better";                                      // input 4
```

I've tried three ways, but not one of these ways does not give me the desired result, which is to find only left word, in this case it is word `"bike"` before searching phrase `"is better"` in all three input cases except **input 3** and without searching phrase itself:

**1)**

```
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?:\S+\s)?\S*is better\S*(?:\s\S+)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var list = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

    foreach (string x in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1) " + x);
    }
```

**2)**

```
     var regex = new Regex(@"(?:is better\s)(?<word>\b\S+\b)");
     var matchCollection = regex.Matches(input);

     foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("2) " + match.Groups["word"].Value);
     }
```

**3)**

```
string pattern = @"(?<before>\w+) is better (?<after>\w+)";           
MatchCollection matche = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matche.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("3) before: " + matche[i].Groups["before"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("3) after: " + matche[i].Groups["after"].ToString());
}
```

With **input 1:** `"I think that green bike is better than the red bike"` results is:

```
1) bike is better than
2) than
3) before: bike
3) after: than
```

So result of `1)` is a both, left and right words of phrase `"is better"`. Result of `2)` is `"then"` word after `"is better"`. And result of `3)` is again both words before and after, exactly what I can use, but problem with this solution is shown in second results.

With **input 2:** `"I think that green bike is better"` result is:

```
1) bike is better
```

Result of `1)` is a word `"bike"` which is before phrase `"is better"` but with searching phrase `"is better"`. Result of `2)` is nothing as it looks for the word after `"is better"`, so it is correct as it is. And result of `3)` is also nothing even if word  `"bike"` is exist before `"is better"` in case if word after  `"is better"` does not exist and it is a last words in string.

With **input 3:**  `"is better than the red one"` results is:

```
1) is better than
2) than
```

Result of `1)` is a exist right word after `"is better"` because left word before does not exist, and again with searching phrase `"is better"` included.  And result `1)` is a word `"then"` after `"is better"`.

And result with **input 4:**  `"bike is better"`:

```
1) bike is better
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\w+(?=\sis better)
```

It will match `bike` except 3rd input.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive way `(\w+) is better` Group 1 : will give you.